# How to show number of caller when forwarding call in twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-python

I have an app using twilio.

I have made the twilio number public and setup call forwarding from that number to my personal number to show alerts both on the app and my phone.

The issue is that I am unable to identify the caller on my phone as it shows the twilio number instead of caller number on my phone.

Is there a possible way to show the caller's number on my phone when forwarding the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. Just don’t set the callerId attribute of the `Dial` verb and it will pass the callerId of the inbound call leg.

Comment: This must need some configurations as currently I am doing just like you said but it shows the twilio number on my phone instead of the caller number. 
Can you please confirm ?

Comment: Here is the doc - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#callerid. Check the Twilio Console  debugger for errors.

Comment: Thanks alot sir, will get back once tested.